# i want to create new fragments programmatically in run-time based on array of objects that will be received from API

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on shopping android app, my app get its data from an API, admin of the app can add Categories for the products using the API, and i am using tabbed activity to display the categories in the customer side.
the question is how i can add new categories' fragmentS programmatically when the admin add this category in the api.
I dont want to update the whole app every time the admin add new category, i just want to make the process automatically, when the admin add new category using the api, the APP will add new fragment.

Comment: If you have to display a similar set of data inside different fragments create them inside a loop where you iterate the categories received from the API and pass the data to the Fragments.

Comment: Thanx about your reply. But the count of categories is not fixed. And so the fragment should be. It can be increased if the admin add new category and can be decreased if the admin delete one. My question id how i can make the app add or delete fragments when the admin add or delete categories